# Responsive mode - window.matchMedia addListener fires button Click() Events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I hope someone can help me with the following problem:

I have set up an addListener function to detect a mobile moving from portrait to landscape mode.  All works perfectly (code below)

```
        var filenameWithExtension = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
        if (filenameWithExtension.indexOf('tool-hire.php') !== -1)
        {
                var mql = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");
                if(mql.matches) {
                                        $('#left-navigation').css({"display": "none"});
                }
                else {
                                    $('#left-navigation').css({"display": "inline"});
                }
                 mql.addListener(function(m)
                {
                    if(m.matches) {
                                        $('#left-navigation').css({"display": "none"});
                    }
                    else {
                                        $('#left-navigation').css({"display": "block"});
                    }
                });   

        }
```

But now, whenever i enter focus into an input box it fires of the hamburger menu click event (code below):

```
    $("#hamburger").click(function () {
            $('#left-navigation').animate({
                opacity: 1,
                left: "50",
                height: "toggle"
              }, 500, function() {  
              });;

        });
```

The menu appears in the screen blocking the input boxes therefore making them unuseable.  I cannot seem to figure out why it is being fired.  I have tried following it in firebug but the problem does not occur in any desktop browser in responsive view.

The problem occurs on android in chrome, firefox, opera and samsung browsers.

Hope that all made sense and i'd be greatful for any suggestions.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: So the inputs are chidlern of hamburger menu or what? You have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue anyway

Comment: No, the inputs are completely separate inputs on the web page.  But hamburger is within #left-navigation div.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to place only the relevant code so as not to crowd the page.